# How to install Android library in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to install the [supertooltips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips) library and I fail every time.

I followed many tutorials, but I ended up with

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Are all the folders and files in the zip necessary, or do I have to put a specific folder in my library folder **"myproject/mylibs"**? And when I try to add the library from **file>new>import module** or right click **project > new > module > import Gradle project** and choose the library; it says project already contains module with this name "**app**" folder.

I'm using the Android Studio 1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your dependencies in your `Module:app` **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nhaarman.supertooltips:library:3.0.+'
}
```

Simply add that line and then just rebuild the project and the library will be added.

Comment: i dont need to download the zip file?

Comment: No, mate. Just add the `compile` line to your gradle ( you have 2 build.gradle files, find the one which has `dependencies` and add it there )

Comment: Did this fix it for you? @tamimabweini

Comment: i put the dependencies in Module:app build.gradle then i went to file>project structure >dependencies >add>library dependency and i added the supertooltips, is that all i need?

Comment: Yes, just rebuild gradle and you can use the library